# Experimenting with multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, reference

I'm experimenting a bit with multi-threading in C++11, and I'm getting some strange results. I have the following code and it runs just fine (`tree_node` is a custom class)

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include "cards.h"
mutex m;

//a function that prints the node and his children
void nodes_print(tree_node& a, std::streampos pos_nodo){

   cout << a.player.suit << a.player.value << "  ";
   cout << a.versus.suit << a.versus.value << "  ";

   if(a.nodes>0){
        for (int i=0; i<a.nodes; i++){
            //children_nodes stores node's children
            nodes_print(a.children_nodes[i], o.tellp());
        }
   }
   else return;
}    

void node_child(tree_node a){
    m.lock();
    cout << "thread " << this_thread::get_id();
    a.children();     //a function member of class tree_node
    nodes_print(a,0); 
    m.unlock();
}

int main(){
   tree_node node_1;
   thread t(node_child, node_1);
   if(t.joinable()) t.join();
   return 0;
}
```

My problem is that I need the function `node_child` to get a reference to `tree_node`. But when i try to use the function `void node_child(tree_node& a)` calling the thread as following

```
tree_node node_1;
thread t(node_child, node_1);
if(t.joinable()) t.join();
```

I get the following error `/usr/include/c++/4.9/functional:1665:61: error: no type named ‘type’ in ‘class std::result_of<void (*(tree_node))(tree_node&)>’`

Searching on internet I found a post where this problem was resolved using `std::ref(node_1)`  wrapper, but I'm wondering what happens when getting that error. In the post I found before the problem was related to more thread accessing the same resource, but can't relate that case to mine since I have only a single thread.

EDIT: adding the definition of `tree_node` in the header `cards.h` included

```
class tree_node{
    tree_node();//ctor
    tree_node(const tree_node&);//copy ctor
    tree_node(tree_node&&); //move ctor
    tree_node& operator= (tree_node);//assignment with copy-swap idiom

    cards * player;
    cards * versus;
    int * suits_player;
    int * suits_versus;
    tree_node * children_nodes;

    void children();

}
```

I'll check the answers as soon as i can, just passed by quickly to check

Comment: show us the definition of a `tree_node` class.

Comment: maybe you should include the header for `tree_node`

Comment: From [this](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57716) gcc bug report page, it looks like the real error is trying to bind an rvalue to an lvalue reference. I'm not sure why the error message would be so terribly unhelpful though.

Comment: You have a compiler error - it can't possibly be related to how many threads you create, or any other run-time aspect of your program; it isn't running yet. Basically, `std::thread` assumes all parameters are being passed by value; `std::ref` is used to tell it otherwise. Without, there's a mismatch between what the function wants to take and what `std::thread` is trying to pass.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  When you used `std::ref(node_1)` after changing the function to  `void node_child(tree_node& a)` did it work?

Comment: @SergeyA He is not using `std::ref` in the code he posted which he must do if passing by reference.  I am just asking if when he used it if he still had an error.

Comment: @NathanOliver, oh, I looked at the code, but I didn't realize this is not the code which gives OP troubles... oh my.

Comment: seems to [compile fine](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9645ea42d514941b)

Comment: @Thomas You forgot to include the change that induces the error. [gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/07e98d93860234d2) and [clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c7f58677d75ac3b) both complain, but my vc++ doesn't. Presumably because a language extension they use extends the lifetime of rvalues bound to lvalue reference parameters until the function returns.

Comment: ok, got it [compiles with & and std::ref](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/927b56d0e3e6ebdf). yes, VC has lifetime extension for non-const references.

Comment: @NathanOliver yes, when writing the function with reference parameter and without `std::ref()` it didn't work, after adding `std::ref` it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the function takes an argument by lvalue reference. Internally, `std::thread` uses `std::decay` that removes the references off the parameter types. When those types are forwarded to the function, the result is passing an rvalue to the reference, which fails.

The reason you don't get a "cannot bind rvalue to lvalue reference" error is because during template instantiation, `std::result_of` is used which deduces the return type by using `decltype` on the function call expression. However, that call is not valid, so `type` is not defined within `result_of`.

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/result_of):

> `type` ... Only defined if F can be called with the arguments ArgTypes... in unevaluated context (since C++14).

`F` (your function) cannot be called, so `type` is never defined, so the compiler  gives you an error for a missing `type` definition.

Comment: This is a mess, thanks for explaining. So the only way to do it is with `std::ref`?